# QGIS 3.16 finding the width and height of bounding boxes

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS 3.16, I have drawn polygons around shapes and found their areas in units of meters**2. Next I have created a shapefile for bounding boxes around these polygons. When I click on the shapefile for the bounding boxes just created, and open the attribute table, I expect to see units for height, width, area, and perimeter in units of meters or meters**2. The units displayed in the image below is unknown. How do I convert all these measurements into meters or meters**2?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer at your question it's necessary to know Coordinate systems worldwide EPSG code or your data reference system (SR).

Maybe that your data are in WGS84 or in other Geographic coordinate system,and so data have measure unit in degrees (or in grads).
You can recalculate your measures in field calculator using **transform()** function, that reprojects your data in a Projected coordinate system, that has measures in meters. For example:

```
transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:32634')
```

where first epsg code is you data SR e second one is the new EPSG code.

If you undestand this passage, then you can calculate
BBox area:

```
area( bounds( transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:32634')))
```

same formula without transform

> area( bounds( $geometry))

bbox heigth

```
bounds_height( ( transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:32634')))
```

same formula without transform

```
>  bounds_height( ($geometry))
```

bbox width:

```
bounds_width( ( transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:32634')))
```

same formula without transform

```
>  bounds_width( ($geometry))
```

Comment: I had figured out that the coordinate system I am using is EPSG:32624. When converting measurements I used area( bounds( transform($geometry,'EPSG:32624','EPSG:32632'))) to convert the area. I had received an area of 4e-06 on one ice berg for example. I verified with the ruler that I should have measured an area near 7436.493 m**2. Do you know why this would have happened?

Comment: if you have EPSG:32624 your SR is 'WGS 84 / UTM zone 24N' [https://epsg.io/32624](https://epsg.io/32624) that has measure units in meter. You don't need to apply trasnsform function. For example, you can calculate area as: area($geometry)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't undestand. EPSG:32624, it is referencing at which layer: bounding box or original feature?
You have to see SR in layer properties.

Comment: I am looking at the bounding boxes shapefile. I had checked the layers CRS and I can see that it is set in EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. From here I open the attribute table. I click on toggle editing mode. I can type $area and $perimeter and get the correct values for the area and perimeter of the boxes. I can confirm this by selecting a box that matches with the ID and using the measuring line. When I try area($geometry) I do not get the correct measurement. But I can by typing $area. So as of right now the main issue I have is height and width. Area and perimeter can be fixed.

Comment: For example when I first open the attribute table, the area of a specific box will be 1.73498e-05. If I then type area($geometry) I then get an area of 1.7e-05. When I type $area, I get an area of 1414992 m**2 which is an area that I can confirm with the measuring tool. I just don't know how to resolve the issue with width and height yet.

Comment: if you use area() function, area is calculated using SR measure units. In your data is EPSG:4326, that have degree as unit.

Comment: You have to use formula with transform(). I change the formula in the answer so to use EPSG:32624 instead of 32632.
Or you can, first reproject your data, saving them as new shapefile and changing SR in EPSG:32624 and then calculating data without transform()